# Getting an error when trying to set NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

Trying to set the width and height of a layout constraint and I am getting the following error:

" Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings failed because either one of the values is nil, or there's something wrong with the way the macro is being invoked.  Cannot assign value nil for key "infoButton". Keys:(
    infoButton "

```
    [holderView addSubview:infoButton];
    // width constraint
    [holderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[infoButton(==44)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(infoButton)]];

    // height constraint
    [holderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[infoButton(==44)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(infoButton)]];
```

UPDATE:

Still not working and when I breakpoint still nil?

```
 [holderView addSubview:infoButton];
    holderView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    id views = @{@"infoButton": infoButton};

    [holderView addSubview:infoButton];
    // width constraint
    [holderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[infoButton(==44)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // height constraint
    [holderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[infoButton(==44)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Comment: you can define this:  id views = @{@"infoButton": self.infoButton}; and use "views" in place of ...metrics:nil views:views]]; instead of that NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings. You might want to make sure your infoButton has been initted and added as a subview before you setup your constraints.

Comment: With your new code, has the error changed? On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: No the issue is still there. And when on my breakpoint it says infoButton is NOT nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `infoButton instance is nil` when you are setting constraint.

Comment: What is the description of infoButton?

Comment: Its a UIButton with the path to its place in memory.

Comment: Print the  uibutton before you setting constraint

Comment: <UIButton: 0x157dbfc0; frame = (250 -46; 44 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x157cf0c0>>

Comment: The issue was that the method that calls the above code is being called twice.